# Getting a value from parent activity returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment working with.
In the activity, i'm initializing the current user like this(manually):

```
User currentUser;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentUser = new User("email", "name", "secondName", "age");
\\.....}
```

the MainActivity contains a method like this :

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
```

now, here is the problem :
in the child fragment i'm calling getCurrentUser from mainActivity like this :

```
User u = MainActivity.newInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

MainActivity.newInstance() - defined in mainActivity like this, returning a static instance of activity :

```
private static MainActivity mainActivityInstance = new MainActivity();

    public static MainActivity newInstance() {
        return mainActivityInstance;
    }
```

the problem is that getCurrentUser returns a null object reference even though currentUser is initialized in mainActivity with valid data.
So, calling for example

```
u.getName();
```

will throw me a NullPointerException
How can i solve this? i feel like i'm freaking out
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> MainActivity.newInstance() - defined in mainActivity like this, returning a static instance of activity :

**Never** create an instance of an activity directly yourself.

> the problem is that getCurrentUser returns a null object reference even though currentUser is initialized in mainActivity with valid data

Those activity instances are separate Java objects.

From a fragment, call `getActivity()` to retrieve the activity object that is hosting the fragment. This is covered in any good book or course on Android app development.

Answer (score 3):

As many people said: "You can't instantiate an Activity in a Fragment".

Second: there are many options you can implement in order to get the User in a Fragment. Here are the common options:

1 - Pass the user as a parameter in the fragment:

```
public static FragmentChild newInstance(User user){
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putSerializable("USER_PARAM",user);
  FragmentChild fragment = new FragmentChild();
  fragment.putArguments(b);
  return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    User user = getArguments().getSerializable("USER_PARAM")
}

public class User implements Serializable {}
```

2 - Use the method ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getCurrentUser(). It will work but if you want to do it in the right way you should use an interface instead of using the MainActivity directly.

Interface option:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserDeliver {

@Override
public User getUser(){
   return user;
}


}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  private UserDeliver userDeliver;      
  private User user;    

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    user = userDeliver.getUser();
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    userDeliver = (UserDeliver) context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   userDeliver = null;
  }

  public interface UserDeliver {
    User getUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you link me to a site with a good reference for interfaces? And maybe an example how to use an interface here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GabiMMinimalART I edited my answer giving you an example with interface. As I said before, it is a matter of good practice. The answer accepted is OK too.

Answer (score 1):

First off-  you can't create an Activity via new.  It will compile, but not be properly initialized because only the framework can do that.

Secondly-  never hold an activity in a static variable.  This will leak memory.  Lots of memory, because the entire view hierarchy has a reference from the Activity.  You will cause OOM errors doing this.

Comment: Thanks for those hints :D

Answer (score 0):

U are generating a newInstance of the MainActivity everytime you do `MainActivity.newInstance()`

Try to retrieve your user with `((MainActivity)getActivity).getCurrentUser();`

Or create the instance of your user in the fragment